# Get Attributes Through One to One Pivot Table in Laravel 5.4

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, relationship, one-to-one

I have an Model called Category. A Category can have multiple Themes. A Theme can only use one Frame. But a Frame can be used by multiple Themes.

My controller method :

```
    $category = Category::find(1);

    foreach ($category->themes as $theme) {

    }


    return response()->json(['category' => $category]);
```

Output :

```
 category: {
        id: 1,
        name: "DemoCategory",
        created_at: null,
        updated_at: null,
        themes: [
        {
        id: 1,
        frame_id: 1,
        created_at: null,
        updated_at: null,
        pivot: {
        category_id: 1,
        theme_id: 1
        }
       }
      ]
    }
```

Theme Model :

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'category_theme');
}

public function frame()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Frame', 'theme_frame');
}
```

Fram Model :

```
empty
```

How can I connect Theme and Frame through a Pivot table ?

And as you can see the themes are nested in the JSON Object. But I also want the Frame for the specific Theme to be nested in the JSON Object. Frame and Theme have a One to One relationship through a pivot table. But as you can see it only returns the id not the whole object. How can I get Frame object nested inside the specific Theme inside the JSON Object ?

Comment: A question would be why would you want the one to one relationship to have a pivot table?

Comment: I thought `hasOne` is only for 1-1 relationships. I would expect the theme to `belongTo`  a frame and the frame to `hasMany` themes.

Comment: @apokryfos - Thank you. I was thinking too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick answer would to define two public variables, one for each model, or to use the with() method on your query, it's as follows:

Category Model:

```
public $with = ['themes'];
```

Theme Model:

```
public $with = ['frame'];
```

Now whenever you are loading a `category` model like `Category::first();`, you will also load the `themes` associated with it, and with each `theme` you will load the `frame` associated with that theme, hopefully this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Also note that this would eager load your relationships every time. If this is your desired outcome then it's fine, but if not this would load the relationships unnecessarily on every fetch.

Comment: That's correct, that's why I said whenever the category model is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the loop, you can eager load the relationship.

```
// with only themes
$category = Category::with('themes')->find(1);

//with themes and frame
$category = Category::with('themes.frame')->find(1);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading